# Align horizontal footer rule to outside margin with memoir class

Tags: header-footer, memoir, double-sided

I'm using the `memoir` document class with the `twoside` option, and want to use a `\textwidth` horizontal rule underneath my header, but a smaller horizontal rule above my footer. Unfortunately, the footer rule is always aligned to the left margin, whereas I want it aligned to the outer margin, above the page number.

Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{memoir}

\copypagestyle{myheadings}{headings}

% add the lines
\makeheadrule{myheadings}{\textwidth}{\normalrulethickness}
\makefootrule{myheadings}{2cm}{\normalrulethickness}{0pt}

% header/footer contents
\makeevenhead{myheadings}{\footnotesize\textsc{chapter \thechapter}}{}{}
\makeoddhead{myheadings}{}{}{\footnotesize\textsc{\MakeLowercase{\leftmark}}}
\makeevenfoot{myheadings}{\footnotesize\thepage}{}{}
\makeoddfoot{myheadings}{}{}{\footnotesize\thepage}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{myheadings}

Test.
\newpage
Test.
\newpage
Test.

\end{document}
```

As you can see, page 2 has the line nicely above the page number, while pages 1 and 3 have the line on the other side.

I have tried to add `\makeheadposition{myheadings}{}{}{\flushleft}{\flushright}`, but that did not change anything.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We first have to load the `etoolbox` package and patch the definition of `\makefootrule`:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\makefootrule}
  {\hrule\@width #2\@height #3 }
  {\rule{#2}{#3}}
  {}
  {}
\makeatother
```

Then we define `\makeheadfootruleprefix` to add the needed space in odd pages:

```
\makeheadfootruleprefix{myheadings}{}{%
  \checkoddpage\ifoddpage\hspace*{\dimexpr\textwidth-2cm\relax}\fi}
```

That's all.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{memoir}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\makefootrule}
  {\hrule\@width #2\@height #3 }
  {\rule{#2}{#3}}
  {}
  {}
\makeatother

\copypagestyle{myheadings}{headings}

% add the lines
\makeheadfootruleprefix{myheadings}{}{%
  \checkoddpage\ifoddpage\hspace*{\dimexpr\textwidth-2cm\relax}\fi}
\makeheadrule{myheadings}{\textwidth}{\normalrulethickness}
\makefootrule{myheadings}{2cm}{\normalrulethickness}{-4pt}

% header/footer contents
\makeevenhead{myheadings}{\footnotesize\textsc{chapter \thechapter}}{}{}
\makeoddhead{myheadings}{}{}{\footnotesize\textsc{\MakeLowercase{\leftmark}}}
\makeevenfoot{myheadings}{\footnotesize\thepage}{}{}
\makeoddfoot{myheadings}{}{}{\footnotesize\thepage}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{myheadings}

Test.
\newpage
Test.
\newpage
Test.

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Notice that I've adjusted `\makefootrule` to have a `-4pt` skip

```
\makefootrule{myheadings}{2cm}{\normalrulethickness}{-4pt}
```

since `\rule` is placed higher than `\hrule`.

Comment: Nice solution, but you are aware that `\rule` and `\hrule` are not placed the same?, `\rule` sits a few mms higher.

Comment: Excellent, thank you. However, the solution does not quite work within a `multicols` environment that stretches multiple pages; the rule is flushed to the right of the first column then. Any thoughts on how to get it to the right of the page instead of the column? (Again I tried to fix it myself, but got stuck.)

Comment: @EelkeSpaak I've changed the answer and now it works even if you use `multicols`.

Comment: @daleif Yes, you're right. Added a fix for that in the answer.

Comment: @karlkoeller Great solution, thank you. I tried something with `\hspace*{}` myself, but could not get it to work.

Comment: @EelkeSpaak You're welcome